# Why the bootstrap.min.css file does not work on an html page?

Tags: bootstrap-4

When downloading the compiled CSS and JS files directly from the boostrap official page (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/) several classes did not work as expected.

Classes that were deemed not to work (there may be many more):

- Border
- Border radius
- Shadow
- Shadow-sm
- flex-fill

Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: when using cdn it works? can you share your code?

Comment: I could solve this problem, the only thing I did was download the bootstrap.min.css file directly from the link "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" with this new file the classes worked correctly.

Comment: In order to get this site benefits you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually you are doing something wrong in your code. It might be you didn't import CSS libraries properly.